# O que é Ergonomia?

Tags: mobile, ux, gui, aplicação-desktop

1) O que o conceito ou significado de Ergonomia?

2) Quais são caraterísticas que um software deve possuir para ser considerado ergonômico?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**1) O que é Ergonomia?**

*Ergonomia (ou "fatores humanos") é a disciplina científica relacionada ao entendimento das interações entre seres humanos e outros elementos de um sistema, e também é a profissão que aplica teoria, princípios, dados e métodos para projetar a fim de otimizar o bem-estar humano e o desempenho geral de um sistema. Os ergonomistas contribuem para o projeto e avaliação de tarefas, trabalhos, produtos, ambientes e sistemas, a fim de torná-los compatíveis com as necessidades, habilidades e limitações das pessoas*

[Wikipedia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergonomia)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### 2) Ergonomia de Software:

### Definição:

ciência que estuda conforto, utilização, organização e documentação do software.
Objetiva facilitar e otimizar o trabalho do usuário junto ao computador.
propõe padrões de:

- apresentação de telas
- diálogos
- ferramentas de trabalho
- cardápios (menus)
- documentação
- técnicas de arquivos
- técnicas de otimização
- auxílio (help)

### Vantagens:

- atração homem-máquina
- programas mais bem documentados
- redução dos custos de manutenção
- software mais eficiente
- software com funções mais poderosas
- facilidade de aprendizado
- redução de perturbações psicológicas do usuário em relação ao computador.

### Desvantagens:

- esforço adicional no desenvolvimento de software.
- como toda novidade ainda afasta técnicos mais antigos.
- técnica nova, ainda em fase de maturação. Ainda não possui muitos antecedentes que comprovem sua eficácia.

[Link](http://www.inf.ufrgs.br/~cabral/INF141.Cap.04.html)

Podes continuar a ler o que está neste ultimo link contem um bom conteúdo.

**2) Quais são caraterísticas que um software deve possuir para tornar-se ergonómico?**

Deves de respeitar:

- Esforço Mínimo do Usuário:
- Memória Mínima do Usuário:
- Frustração Mínima:
- Maximizar o uso de padrões e hábitos:
- Máxima tolerância para diferenças humanas:
- Máxima tolerância para mudanças ambientais:
- Notificação imediata de problemas:
- Controle máximo de tarefas pelo usuário:
- Apoio máximo às tarefas;

*(explicação destes tópicos no [LINK](http://www.inf.ufrgs.br/~cabral/INF141.Cap.04.html))*

Comment: vlw obrigado +1 no seu post^^

Comment: @PedroRangel, sem tirar o mérito aqui da resposta do jsantos, é legal esperar um par de dias antes de marcar uma resposta como aceita, isso dá mais chances de atrair outras respostas.

Comment: @brasofilo obrigado pelo conselho... vou acatar ele.

Comment: Muito boa resposta. Porém há dois pontos muito discutíveis no item "Desvantagens". O primeiro deles é que a ergonomia, como um elemento importante da usabilidade (hoje parte de UX), não é assunto novo (o [famoso livro Human-Computer Interaction](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Human-Computer-Interaction-Jenny-Preece/dp/0201627698) de Jenny Preece é de 1994!). O segundo é que há sim muitos antecedentes que comprovam não somente a eficácia, como o alto custo da falta desse esforço. Um ótimo vídeo introdutório sobre o Retorno do Investimento com UX é esse: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O94kYyzqvTc

Comment: @LuizVieira obrigado, para te dizer na verdade não sou muito entendido no assunto, conhecia o termo no geral e depois de uma pesquisa(pelo interesse relacionado com o software) consegui realizar essa resposta... Contudo concordo com os teus dois pontos, mesmo sendo como tu dissestes muito discutíveis, porque ainda não é aquele assunto que toda a gente conhece(se o fosse possivelmente esta pergunta não existiria), quero me referir não há falta de informação mas sim há falta de implementação por parte das instituições(Empresas, Escolas, etc)*[Continua]*

Comment: por isso de certa forma pode-se dizer que é um assunto novo... Isto é a minha opinião, posso estar enganado

Comment: @jsantos1991 Por nada. Eu entendo, mas não se preocupe, eu só quis na verdade complementar a resposta (e não questioná-la). :)